# Android ошибка при получении кординат gps

Tags: java, android, gps

**В логах нули**

```
public class GpsLocation {
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
public static final String TAG = "gps_debug_logs";

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();


        Log.d(TAG, "Latitude=" + location.getLatitude());
        Log.d(TAG, "longitude=" + location.getLongitude());

   }

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}


};

public double getLatitude() {

return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
    }}
```

**Пермишн есть**

```
<uses-permission `android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE"/>`

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: не плохо бы еще показать вызов данного класса

Answer (score 1):

Вызов метода в main activity .

```
 GpsLocation gps = new GpsLocation();

    Log.d(TAG, "Longitude= " +  gps.getLongitude());
    Log.d(TAG, "Latitude= " + gps.getLatitude());
```